# Add event to google calender

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am trying to integrate my webapp with google calender, My app is used by several users which is having events that i want to push onto their google calender,

I want to provide one time authorization process to manage his google calender.

I created project in google api console to access calender API's and am using google calender PHP library to get authorization.

I have ClientId, Secret, Redirect Uri, Developer Key, so i got CODE from google after authorization.

Can i use offline way to create event instead of authorizing him every time....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was bale to solve the problem using following steps

- Created developer account in Google developer console.
- Created one project in Google developer console
- Give permission to app to google calender.
- Create Public API access for browser applications
- Create New client ID for web app using Authorized redirect URI and Javascript Origins.
- Used Google library to validate authentication and get refresh token from google.
- Stored refresh token to database for future.

All above five points are one time activity.

- Get new access token using refresh token to insert/update/delete
  events in google calender of user

This Sixth Activity is based on the event what we want to do.

This has solved my problem, refresh token will stay for life-long, we can get access token from refresh token to do calender operation.

How it works:
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2InstalledApp